# Error with permissions to a provider hosted app - 'Only Tenant admins can add/give access to app'

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

I am trying to deploy a Provider Hosted App to my Sharepoint o365 Dev Site.
I am getting the following error - 
[image]

I am logged into the site as **a tenant administrator**

The app needs to have (and configured in app manifest) -

1. Tenant Level Access
2. Manage to User Profiles

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your app is requesting full control of all site collections in the tenant ,  tenant admin permission is required.

You can follow the below steps:

1) Upload the app to the app catalog.

2) Go the site contents in the site collection where you want to install the app.

3)Click on your app to install, it will display a message "You can't add app here"" Find out why" (see below screenshot) or you can click on trust it.

[image]

4) You can click on request approval as below:

[image]

5) The app approval request goes to tenant admin who has to approve the app installation.

Tenant admin has to browse to app catalog and check the app requests pending for approval.

So, go to your App catalog site collection.There you will find the the `app requests` section as below.

[image]

6) Click on the app requests link.

7) Find and click on your app, it will open the approval screen as below:

[image]

8) Here, click on the Approve button.

9) Now, go to your site collection and add the app again.

10) It will ask the permission, click on trust it again and then your app will be added to your site collection.

Ref - [Request app installation permissions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Request-app-installation-permissions-5a25c5b0-bdfb-49f8-8ca3-046edc9cf598?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

If you are tenant admin and want to approve this. Use `https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx` I have the same error but not in SharePoint admin center.